# file_get_contents file permission issue reading a pem file

Tags: php, ssh-keys, phpseclib, file-exists

Firstly the code test below was working for the first pem file I tried but when I tried another pem file it failed. I changed permissions and now I can't read any pem files with file_get_content.

My goal here is to load the pem file into php to use with phpseclib on a remote. All the process works on my local dev box (which is on windows) but not on an ubuntu box. Using stat, file_exists and is_readable all also return false. My assumption is that I've got the permissions all wrong but hit a wall getting them right. Of note i include the same path to the pem file in an rsync command and this works.

I've tried using chmod with 777, 755, 600, 644, 666 none worked. i tried chown with www-data:me me:me www-data:www-data and me:www-data

The files are in a .ssh folder which has permissions of 0700 with user me:me

The file for definite exists if i do a nano and paste the file name (ie sudo nano /home/me/.ssh/the_pem_file.pem then i can view the contents

```
use phpseclib\Crypt\RSA;

$path = $_POST['path'];

if (!$GLOBALS['cygwin']) {
    $new_path = str_replace( '~', '/home/me', $path ); //Dev Windows
} else {
    $new_path = str_replace( '~', 'C:/Users/Me', $path ); // Live Linux
}
clearstatcache();
$exists = file_exists( $new_path );
$is_readable = is_readable( $new_path );
if ( $exists || $is_readable) {
    $perms = decoct( fileperms( $new_path ) & 0777 );
    if ( $perms == 0600 ) {
        //Not implemented test
    }
    $key = new RSA();

    $pub = file_get_contents($new_path);
    if ($key->load($pub)) {
        $sshPass = $key;
    } else {
        var_dump($pub);
        var_dump($key);
        die($path);
    }
...........
} else {
    $pub = file_get_contents($new_path);
    var_dump( $pub );
    var_dump( stat( $new_path ) );
    var_dump( $new_path );
    var_dump( $exists );
    var_dump( $is_readable );
}
```

the output on the webpage is

```
{removed path}:boolean false

{removed path}:boolean false

{removed path}:string '/home/me/.ssh/the_pem_file.pem' (length=??)

{removed path}:boolean false

{removed path:boolean false
```

As pointed out this was working with one of my pem files but not the other until i changed permissions. Now neither work. Permissions originally where 600 with www-data:me but this no longer works.

Notice i have used clearstatcache() before the tests and i double check loading the file in the error section of the code just in case it actually is working but file_exists is returning false as a false positive.

Spent too long on this so any help guidance or suggestions would be appreciated. I also looked over other posts here with similar issues but none seemed to fit my scenario (most used urls or paths relative to doc root, my understanding that a full path is preferred)

thanks

Craig

Comment: Didn't you change permissions of `.ssh` folder itself? What does `glob("/home/me/.ssh/*")` return?

Comment: I think i changed the .ssh folder while trying to get this to work prior to this thread. You hit it on the head though the glob returned an empty array. I set the permission with sudo chown www-data .ssh and it seems to be now adding the pem file as expected. I'll just check that the main scripts are working now.

Comment: After amending the .ssh files I'm now unable to do a git pull on this server. I read that the permissions of the files in the .ssh have specific permissions ie id_rsa.pub is 644 and the rest are 0600 I currently have chown as www-data:me git works if this is me:me completely lost now. Surely it can't be that it works with git or my script? I should also mention i have the same keys as symbolic links in var/www/.ssh and these are set to 777 (don't seem to be able to change this)

Answer (score 0):

In the end i removed the pem files from /home/me/.ssh and put them in /var/www/.ssh removing the symlinks i had here. I amended code to use /var/www/.ssh which has chown www-data:www-data so no issues with it and git worked